# ggplot map fill with gradient color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am filling `ggplot + geom_sf` with colors. Most values (`value_pop`) in my data are between 1-30, with very few outliers reaching values of up to 350.

My code looks like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=value_pop))+
  geom_sf()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(6,"RdYlBu")),
                       name="Susirgimai\n/100.000 gyventojų",
                       na.value = "grey100", 
                       values =  rescale(seq(0, 400, length.out = 6)))
```

What I would like to have is a following scale/legend and accordingly the coloring of the map

[image]

, so I would see the variation of lower values in the map, but my code yields

[image]

Any suggestions on how to change the `scale_fill_gradientn(...)` parameters, so that I can set manually the values? I would rather not cut my `value_pop` into groups, but leave it numerical.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps you want to set the `breaks =` parameter in `scale_fill_gradientn`?

Comment: @AllanCameron unfortunately in `scale_fill_gradientn()` e.g. `breaks=c(1,3,5,10,100,1000)` only prints on current legend the breaks (ticks+numbers), but does not affect how these breaks are associated with colors and does not affect the coloring of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a log transform with `trans = log`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$value_pop <- c(sample(1:30, nrow(nc)-6, replace = TRUE), 66, 120, 150, 200, 330, 350)
my_breaks <- c(1, 3, 10, 32, 100, 316, 1000)
ggplot(nc, aes(fill = value_pop)) +
    geom_sf()+
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(magma(6)),
                         name="Susirgimai\n/100.000 gyventojų",
                         na.value = "grey100", 
                         trans = "log",
                         breaks = my_breaks, labels = my_breaks)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very, very much!!! This worked exactly as intended!